# Search in ruby by many fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I need to search form multiple fields in my app, using textfield and combo-box. I have Items that belongs to genre, location, user and affectation. This is what I did.

Item.rb

```
def self.search(query)  
where("cod ilike :q or den_cont ilike :q or marca ilike :q", q: "%#{query}%")
end
```

Item.controller

```
@items = Item.joins("LEFT JOIN calibrations on items.id = calibrations.item_id")
.select(" items.id, items.codigo, items.numero, items.den_cont, items.marca,     items.modelo, items.nro_serie, items.genre_id, items.state_id, items.affectation_id,    items.sector_id, items.person_id, MAX(calibrations.date_expired) as date_expired,   items.observaciones")
.group("items.id")
.order("items.codigo, items.numero").search(params[:search])
else
...
end
```

Index.html

```
<%= form_tag(items_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Buscar Items" %>
<%= submit_tag "Buscar", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see I can search for codigo, den_cont and marca in the same texfield. I need seach for multiples fields, but in deferents text-box and in the case of genre, state..i need a combo-box to select the value and then search. Can you gave me some example or help on this. What about using a gem for this. (searchkick fot example). Tks!

Comment: not sure I 100% understand the question but have you looked at `ransack` it has some really nice form builders for advanced searches [Railscast #370](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack)

Comment: Tks Engin...I'll take a look. Just need search by genre, location and user using dropdown box. I have the id's in table Items and also search using 3 text box instead one (codigo, den_cont and marca)..